# apache http: redirect to https:

Tags: apache, ssl, httpd.conf

I'm trying to configure my apache server to redirect to `https://` when a user browses to the `http://` url.

I've searched around google, but things aren't quite working. Here's what I've tried:

```
Listen 443
….
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/server.key"

    SSLProxyEngine On
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
</VirtualHost>

ErrorLog /usr/local/apache2/logs/error.log
CustomLog /usr/local/apache2/logs/access.log combined

FallbackResource /index.html
```

With this configuration, this is the browsers response:

```
################## Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
```

Additionally, I've tried this one:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/server.key"

    SSLProxyEngine On
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
```

But to no avail (same browser response).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you restarting Apache when you make the changes? Also it's worth checking that you have https correctly first before testing the redirect. Can you browse to the https url?

Answer (score 0):

Looking on the second example i'd say the rewrite part should go into the standard host, *:80...

Also, maybe the error message comes from not having a server ready which is able to deliver at least the redirect via http...